# when i use phpbrew install php on my Mac, play phpbrew fpm start give me notice

Tags: macos

at first my english not good! thx read my title and hope someone can fix my question!
when i use phpbrew install my php on my Mac ,when i use phpbrew fpm start it give me a notice:like:
[05-Nov-2014 20:16:14] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root

05-Nov-2014 20:16:14] NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root

hope someone can tell me how to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

It's normal and expected. basically you can ignore it.